# EagleView/Pictometry : Cannot read property 'isCollection' of undefined at i._walkAnnotations

Tags: javascript, maps

I'm integrating with EagleView's Pictometry maps API.

Why does this issue occur when I'm making a standard `addShapes()` request. This is what I'm doing:

I've instantiated the PictometryHost as `this.ipa` and I have an array `squares` of latLong pairs like this: `{lat: xxx, lng: xxx}`

```
    const squarePolygons = squares.map((square) => {
      const shape = {
        type: this.ipa.SHAPE_TYPE.POLYGON,
        coordinates: panel,
        strokeColor: 'white',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 1.0,
        fillColor: '#000000',
        fillOpacity: 1.0,
      }
      return shape
    })

    this.ipa.addShapes(panelPolygons)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This happens when you send an invalid property on the `shape` object.**

Not a very helpful error message, obviously. Having finally figured it out, thought I'd put this here in case it helps others. Basically, this opaque error is thrown when any invalid property is received by the Pictometry API.

In this case, the `coordinates` property was an array of objects, which is correct, but each coordinate has to be in the format `{x: [], y: []}` rather than straight lat/lng pairs.

See the [`addShapes` documentation](https://pol.pictometry.com/ipa/v1/docs/ipa/#!/api/PictometryHost-method-addShapes) here for more.

Also, Pictometry doesn't recognize html colors, so the `strokeColor` property has to be "`#FFFFFF`" instead of "white".